# I am trying to pop 4 values of list in python at the last but I am not getting these values right

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**I am not getting the right values of the list at the last when I pop values from the list**

```
 invitation = ['Abbas', 'Rafy', "sherry"]
    for i in range(0,3):
        print("Hi, I am inviting you to dinner at my place Mr." + invitation[i].title())
    print("Just in Mr."+invitation[2].title()+" could not attend the dinner due to his arrogance")
    invitation[2]='ateeq'
    print(invitation)
    for i in range(0,3):
        print("Hi, I am inviting you to dinner at my place Mr." + invitation[i].title())
    print("Just in I have found a bigger table now three more people can eat")
    invitation.insert(0, 'ahmad')
    invitation.insert(2, 'salman')
    invitation.append('Usman')
    print(invitation)

for i in range(0,6):
    print("Hi, I am inviting you to dinner at my place Mr." + invitation[i].title())

print("Sorry guys I can only invite two people")
print(invitation)
for i in range(0,4):
    print("you are out "+invitation.pop(i))
print(invitation)
```

Comment: This is what ```pop()``` does - *Removes the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If no index is specified, ```pop()``` removes and returns the last item in the list.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pop` method is not working as you think:
Let us simulate the following:

```
for i in range(0,4)
```

The list is:

```
['ahmad', 'Abbas', 'salman', 'Rafy', 'ateeq', 'Usman']
```

It is taking the nth element of the edited list.

```
i=0
invitation.pop(i)
List element to  be popped: ['ahmad', 'Abbas', 'salman', 'Rafy', 'ateeq', 'Usman']
                                ^
i=1
invitation.pop(i)
List element to  be popped: ['Abbas', 'salman', 'Rafy', 'ateeq', 'Usman']
                                         ^
i=2
invitation.pop(i)
List element to  be popped: ['Abbas', 'Rafy', 'ateeq', 'Usman']
                                                 ^
i=3
invitation.pop(i)
List element to  be popped: ['Abbas', 'Rafy', 'ateeq', 'Usman']
                                                                 ^
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

The `pop` method is actually skipping one element as you iterate over the loop.

Instead, you should do list slicing:

```
invitation=invitation[4:]
print(invitation)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is way too much code for the question you are asking.

I've looked at two line before last - the ones with loop and pop. The problem is you are passing pop increasing values of i. pop removes an element at a given index, which means that all following indexes (or rather elements at these indexes) shift forward. So, in a loop you remove index 0 and now all the remaining elements  have new indexes still starting from 0. Then you remove index 1, which means you've skipped index 0 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
invitation = ['Abbas', 'Rafy', "sherry"]
    for i in range(0,3):
        print("Hi, I am inviting you to dinner at my place Mr." + invitation[i].title())
    print("Just in Mr."+invitation[2].title()+" could not attend the dinner due to his arrogance")
    invitation[2]='ateeq'
    print(invitation)
    for i in range(0,3):
        print("Hi, I am inviting you to dinner at my place Mr." + invitation[i].title())
    print("Just in I have found a bigger table now three more people can eat")
    invitation.insert(0, 'ahmad')
    invitation.insert(2, 'salman')
    invitation.append('Usman')
    print(invitation)

    for i in range(0,6):
        print("Hi, I am inviting you to dinner at my place Mr." + invitation[i].title())

    print("Sorry guys I can only invite two people")
print(invitation)
for i in range(0,4):
    print("you are out "+invitation.pop())
print(invitation)
```

Just removing i from the pop will work perfectly for you!